# How to start Android app installed from Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

If app is terminated from Studio, it will not available on device? I want to start it direcetly from device, but no app icon I can see to touch it and launch.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.j4nos.moviebuffs6">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: show your manifest.xml

Comment: This is not normal behaviour, Did you try with other devices?

Comment: As per your manifest.xml , the launcher icon should appear in menu. kindly check other devices too.

Comment: Though settings I was able to start, but not from main screen.

Comment: did you tried with different devices?

Comment: try with another one. i think this is not common problem

Comment: Has your app been deployed successfully to your phone?

Answer (score 0):

You can download the app ASTRO file browser and try to look for the app using that instead of the list of all installed apps.